# How to split a stream and recombine the sub-streams final results in RxJs

Tags: rxjs

I have a source stream that can emit two types of messages. I would like to separate them into two separate streams and once the original stream complete, re-combine their final emitted value (or get undefined if none exists).

e.g

```
const split1$ = source$.pipe(
     filter(m) => m.kind === 1, 
     mergeMap(m) => someProcessing1());
const split2$ = source$.pipe(
     filter(m) => m.kind === 2, 
     mergeMap(m) => someProcessing2());
forkJoin(split1$, split2$).subscribe(
(output1, output2) => console.log(output1, output2));
```

The problem is that nothing guarantee that both split1$ and split2$ will emit values. If that happens, forkJoin never emits.
With what can I replace forkJoin to emit a value whenever the source stream completes.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About splitting the stream:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html

About "emit on complete", can't you just use `complete` callback instead? `.subscribe(() => console.log('Emitted"), null, () => console.log('Completed'))`;

Otherwise you can use `startWith` operator to make sure something was emitted.

```
const [evens, odds] = source.pipe(partition(val => val % 2 === 0));
evens = evens.pipe(startWith(undefined)); // This will emit undefined before everything, so forkJoin will surely emit
```

Add `startWith` in the `forkJoin` constructor:

```
forkJoin(evens.pipe(startWith(undefined)), odds.pipe(startWith(undefined)))
  .subscribe(console.log))
```

Comment: I can't use the complete call back because i want to use the resulted data after all streams are done
StartWith is a valid option, but will introduce noise to me code because i'll have to filter it if i do any login in the splitted stream pipe.

Comment: Just log before `startWith` or add `startWith` in `forkJoin` contructor so you don't change initial partitioned stream. Edited the answer.